# MathProg / GLPSol - "Too many rows"

Tags: rows, linear-programming, limits, glpk, mathprog

I have been using a MathProg model with glpsol to solve a problem, and it works perfectly when the problem is small enough.

But, when the problem grows, I get a "too many rows" error:

```
GLPSOL: GLPK LP/MIP Solver, v4.61
Parameter(s) specified in the command line:
 --gomory --pcost -d data.dat -m model.mod -o stats.out -y result.out
Reading model section from model.mod...
86 lines were read
Reading data section from data.dat...
data.dat:10419: warning: final NL missing before end of file
10419 lines were read
Generating res_connection_data_elem_path...
Generating res_elems...
Generating res_sizes...
Generating cost...
Model has been successfully generated
glp_add_rows: nrs = 102000101; too many rows
Error detected in file api/prob1.c at line 259
```

I have checked this https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-glpk/2013-12/msg00006.html, where they say that the limit can be changed, so I opened the source code to change it, seeing a comment which alerts not to change the limit.

What could I do?

Comment: You may want to see if you can reformulate your model. Models with > 1e8 rows are very large (you would probably need commercial solvers and ample memory for that).